# Need Different Versioned Dependencies In the Same Project

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a project that has two needed dependencies for it. These dependencies have in turn apache cxf dependencies. Dependency A uses apache cxf versions 2.4.0 where dependency B uses apache cxf versions 3.1.0.

Because classes were changed between the versions, using one or the other results in ClassNotFoundException's.

A little description of what they are, Dependency A is the client jar for some old SOAP webservices. This includes the autogenerated files from wsdl2java. Dependency B is the client jar for a new REST webservice.

The main project uses Maven to handle dependencies, is a war, and is on tomcat 7.

Any thoughts for what I could do to try and get this to work correctly? I have already tried making the REST client a jar-with-dependencies and bringing it in through Tomcat's common classloader with no luck.

**EDIT**

After reviewing the dependencies I am bringing in, I can't simply update the dependencies because I do not have control of some of the dependencies being brought in. I would need to alter what those jars are doing and that will not work.

Comment: well that failed to add the images...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its never a good idea to use two version of same dependency as it can create discrepancies in your project.
Ideally you should latest version and then make the old code compatible with latest version

Comment: Thats kind of what I was thinking needed to be my next step but was trying to avoid because I personally am not sure how changing the dependency affects the autogenerated files I already have. Maybe I'm just thinking to much about this. I'm going to edit the question with relating information in a min.

Comment: +1. While you could do a workaround via something like the dependency plugin, maven is trying to help out here. Either MSach's solution or  something via profiles to have separate builds if absolutely necessary.

Comment: +1 I wish I could say this is what I did but there were some other politics getting in the way. Regardless this is the route that I feel would be the best fit to this question if it had been as simple as my question made the issue to be.